# Show a piecewise function is a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be  a function defined as follows:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      mx & x\in \Bbb Q\Bbb\cap[0,1] \\
      m(x-1) & \text{Otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$ where $m>0.$ Discuss the continuity of $f$. Here is my attempt:

Claim: $f$ is discontinuous everywhere.  Let $c\neq 0$, we will show that $f$ is not continuous at $c..$ Conisder cases for $c$:

Case I: If $c$ is a rational number. By the density of irrational numbers, we can find a sequence $x_n$ of irrational numbers such that $x_n$ converges to $c.$   So, $f(x_n)=m(1-x_n)$ which converges to $m(1-c)$ but $f(c)=mc$ and   $m(1-c)\neq mc$.  So,that means, $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(c)$. Thus, $f$ is not at $c$.

Case II: If $c$ is an irrational number. The argument will quite similar.

**Edit**. There was an error in the OP and I changed based on Mr.
Andreas comment.

I think everything works well now.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, yes it was a typo.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, your argument in Case II ($x$ is an irrational number) is wrong. You showed $|f(x)|<2m$ but this upper bound is a nonzero constant, so there are $\epsilon$ such that no choice of $\delta$ will make $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

In fact, your first argument for the discontinuity of $f$ at rational numbers applies at $0$ too, no reason to exclude it.

Comment: @Andreas: Beat me to it. (E.g., suppose $m = 1$. Then there are irrational $x$ arbitrarily close to $x = 0$ that are $< -1/2$, but $f(0) = 0$.)

Comment: @Andreas,  To be honest I am not sure about the irrational case I just made it up If  is not continuous for very $x.$

Answer (score 1):

Because of the density we can choose some sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ that are in rational and irrational numbers in $[0, 1]$ respectively, such as both converge to some $x_0\in[0, 1]$. So if the function were continuous then the limits of $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n) $ would be the same, but $mx_0=m(x_0-1) $ does not hold for any real number, thus is discontinuous at every point

Comment: the function is defined on $[0,1]$ Only

Comment: Yes, My bad. I read it wrong